# FileMaker Pro 12 Advanced IWP on FileMaker Server 13

Tags: webserver, filemaker

Is it possible to use FileMaker Server 13's new WebDirect system to serve Instant Web Publishing solutions that were developed and maintained in FileMaker Pro 12 Advanced?

I've enabled IWP from within FMP 12 Advanced and can connect via web browser while it is running in FMP. Once I copy it to FileMaker Server it no longer has web running on the project.

The demo project (FMServer_Sample.fmp12) that came with FileMaker Server 13 runs web by default and works fine from Server. IF I open FMServer_Sample.fmp12 in FileMaker 12 Advanced it will not show up in the FMP IWP list in my web browser. I can open FMServer_Sample.fmp12 in FMP12 Advanced and make edits and saves, and it will still work in FM Server 13 WebDirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under the Extended Privileges tab of Manage > Security. It's the presence or absence of the "fmwebdirect" or "fmiwp" extended privilege that determines who can access the file.

If you had opened the file with FM13 (Pro or Advanced), it would have created the missing privilege for you. But you can manually add it.

Note that FM13 no longer automatically creates the fmiwp privilege, but if you open a FM13 file in FM12 it will add it.

Don't forget to assign the extended privilege to a privilege set. That's why the sample file didn't show up in your IWP list in the web browswer.